# How to print the list of filesystem in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems

What I'm trying to do is to list the all of the registered filesystem in a linux kernel module.I tried writing code like below in reference to find_filesystem(http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.19/source/fs/filesystems.c) in fs/filesystems.c.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>       // for basic filesystem

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static struct file_system_type *file_systems;


void list_filesystem(void){
    struct file_system_type **p;
    for(p=&file_systems; *p; p=&(*p)->next){
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n",(*p)->name);
    }
}
static int __init filesystem_list_init(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loaded list_filesystem module\n");
    list_filesystem();
    return 0;
}

static void __exit filesystem_list_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "list_filesystem module unloaded \n");
}


/* Declaration of the init and exit functions */
module_init(filesystem_list_init);
module_exit(filesystem_list_exit);
```

I expected that this list all of the filesystem.
but it doesn't show any filesystem name.
so please let me know what' wrong with this code and how this should be modified.

Answer (score 0):

In your module you cannot iterate over filesystems list, because the head of that list - `file_systems` variable - is **inaccessible** for you: the source file which implements filesystem list declares the variable as **static**. You have tried to create *your own instance* of variable, but this is just a *new list*. As nobody fills it, it is empty.

Current implementation of the filesystem's list doesn't provide methods for iterate over original list in an outer code. One may only obtain filesystem list in *textual representation* by reading file `/proc/filesystems`.

Comment: As you say that file_systems variable is inaccessible,is this variable used to be accessible?

Comment: Do you mean whether this variable was accessible to outer world in previous Linux kernel versions? If so, just check source code of previous versions. Note, that for use variable in a module, aside from being non-static the variable should be **exported** (with `EXPORT_SYMBOL`).